# Oracle sql developer trigger error ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.LRES_PROTOKOLL'

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I create a trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER trj2
  BEFORE  INSERT OR UPDATE OF
  customer_ID ON Reserve
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  new_fk1_NR VARCHAR2(7);
BEGIN
  SELECT NR
      INTO new_fk1_NR
      FROM  customers
      WHERE   :NEW.customer_ID= customers.ID;  
      :NEW.NR_K := new_fk1_NR;
END;
```

It is working fine for update statements, but for insert it give this error

> ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.WRITERESPROT", line 76
>   ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.LRES_PROTOKOLL", line 38 
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.LRES_PROTOKOLL'

I couldn't find links or explanations about what does this mean,
any help please?

Comment: What do you want to do when the `SELECT INTO` returns no record?

Comment: I want to say "this could not happen since customer does not exist"

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please do **NOT** create your own tables and triggers in the SYSTEM tablespace. (or use the `SYSTEM`  account for your regular work). That is a really, really bad idea. Create a regular user and create all your things there. Don't use the SYSTEM or SYS accounts

Comment: "this could not happen since customer does not exist" - that is exactly when it *could* happen, as there is no customer row to find. Anyway... the error message refers to trigger `lres_protokoll`, but your code is for a trigger called `trj2` - which doesn't call `writeresprot` so I don't think you've just changed the name inconsistently. The trigger you've shown doesn't seem to be relevant?

Comment: `ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.LRES_PROTOKOLL'` - this is not the trigger you've included in your question. The actual error occurs in a function or procedure name `SYSTEM.WRITERESPROT` at line 76, but you also haven't shown us this. ???

Comment: thank you, you helped me to find the source of the problem. The error is produced when I use my trigger, but the error is from lres_protokoll trigger, there are some constraints that did not fulfill... now the problem is fixed, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when no rows are returned.  A simple way to ensure that *exactly* one row is returned is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(NR)
INTO new_fk1_NR
FROM customers
WHERE :NEW.customer_ID = customers.ID;
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` returns exactly one row, even when no rows match.  If no rows match, the result is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

This error is raised becaue your `SELECT ... INTO ...` query returned no record. You would need to either ensure that the query always returns one record, or to handle that exception.

Something like this will handle exceptions:

```
create or replace trigger trj2
    before  insert or update of customer_id on reserve
    for each row
declare
    new_fk1_nr varchar2(7);
begin

    select nr into new_fk1_nr from customers where :new.customer_id= customers.id;  
    :new.nr_k := new_fk1_nr;

    exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND
        then raise_application_error(
            -20010,
            'this could not happen since customer does not exist'
        );
    when others
        then raise_application_error(-20011,'Unknown Exception');

end;
/
```

Comment: I have added the exception handling but it gives me the same result

Comment: The trigger you've posted in your question is not the trigger referenced by the error message. So are you sure you've edited the correct trigger???

Comment: @APC, you're right, two other triggers are called when I use my trigger.. and the problem is related to one of them.. now the problem is fixed.